# Remove a GET listener in express-js

Tags: node.js, express

I have created a module in nodejs that will have express serve a directory as if it was the root directory without "hogging" the root ('/') GET listener.

It does this by scanning the requested directory and adding get listeners according to the files and folders within it.

Now I am trying to add a listener on that directory and add/remove listeners if files or folders are added/removed from that directory.

My problem is that I couldn't find a way to remove get listeners in express. I can only add them.

How do I undo the following code:

`app.get('some/url/path', (req,res) => { res.end('good') });`

or in other words, how do I free the `'some/url/path'` listener?

Comment: You could make callback return 404. That would be equivalent for client as having no route for that path.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point here, but why can't you use [`express.static()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static)?

Comment: @robertklep you're not missing the point, I was. I just didn't know about it. I will now use that instead (too bad I spent so much time on my module though)

Comment: @TomKlino on the other hand, you probably learned a thing or two while implementing it, so not all time was wasted =D